# Same application and directory but different web.config files?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I doubt this is possible but one of our web applications is used by customers whereby they have a live/test database.  At the moment updates have to go to both folders as there is a directory setup for both and the web.config file points to either the live or the test.

Is there some way I can use just the one directory but 2 web apps in IIS each using a different web.config file or something similar so only 1 place needs to be updated?

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you would have to maintain things in a slightly different way. What you're not telling us is: Are the only places that you're using the separation of config values is in `connectionStrings` and `appSettings`? Or are there other differences?

Then you would really need to load these values out of a separate config file, not referenced by the existing config file, and not loaded using `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` or any of its namespaces/utilities. The next step would be to use the incoming URL to segregate the data being used by the settings class to know which of the two data points to load.

Otherwise, if you were to write the app in this manner, this is perfectly valid (just kind of goes against what we're used to doing in the rest of the world).

Comment: They are within the connection file, essentially have two directories with exactly the same files but different connectionString

Comment: Nope, can't be done with the "built-in libraries". Microsoft didn't write the app structure to do this, so in all fairness, you'll just need to write your own loader.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your database connection system, you could supply it with a connectionstring based on a usersetting rather than based on the web.config? There has to be some way of deciding which database a user wants to use, this could be something as simple as buttons or dropdown list for selecting, or keep the system with two folders but use an URL route to make them both point to the same files. Then when you instantiate your database connection you can supply the correct connectionstring and you're set.

**Edit**: After chat the solution has been to put two connectionstrings in `web.config`, one for the Test database and one for Production. Then add routing to pretend the two folders are still there, with the following basic idea:

```
routes.Add(new Route("{folder}/{page}", new PageRouteHandler("~/{page}")));
```

Lastly a function to decide which connectionstring to use based on the `folder` value in the routing values: `Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["folder"]`, and a global refactor to use this dynamic connectionstring rather than a hardcoded one.

---

For having "multiple" web.configs, you can make a config section specific to a file path, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx However I am not sure wheter this works for connectionstrings.

Example:

```
<configuration>
   <location path="Logon.aspx">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks but need the connection to come from the web.config

Comment: You can't specify more than one connectionstring path, no. And it has to live in the app itself, it can't go negative in the filesystem.

Comment: If the connectionstring has to come from web.config, this does not have to be a problem. You can read the connectionstrings from web.config manually and supply them to the database connection explicitly. Add two connectionstrings, eg `ConnectionLive` and `ConnectionTest`, and access them with [ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings.aspx).

Comment: I realise I can add another connectionstring but how do you define which one is used throughout for that particular app? Also as everything in my app is looking for a specific connectionstring this will be really time consuming to change to check the necessary connection everywhere.

Comment: Make a central way of creating your database connection and update your app to always use this. It's a one-time refactor, but surely the best way to handle this.

Comment: Not sure how you would intend I do this, could you provide example?

Comment: How do you access database? `DataContext`, `DbContext`, `SqlConnection`?

Comment: A connection string like so:

    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SessionPlanner" connectionString="Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=databasename;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17707/discussion-between-willem-duncan-and-user1166905)

Comment: Now bring those answers back into your answer so folks can find the answer more neatly.